# Background-Image does not display correctly in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an extremely simple website with a simple horizontal menu that appears to be working in all browsers except IE8 (and potentially older but I don't have access to test).

I refer to "Background-Image" in the question because I went through a small process of elimination and found that the menu works (albeit without the background-image) when I omit the Background-Image from the code.

The CSS Code here:

```
    .cssmenu ul {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .cssmenu a {
        display: block;
        /*width: 6em;*/
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;

     }
     .cssmenu a:hover {
        display: block;
        /*width: 5em;*/
        color: #46a446;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
     }

     .cssmenu li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1.5em;
        background-image: url('Images/Dark_Green_Beveled_Circle.jpg');
        background-position:left center;
        background-size: 16px 16px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        white-space: nowrap;            
            }
            .cssmenu li:hover {
        background-image: url('Images/Light_Green_Beveled_Circle.jpg');
        background-position:left center;
        background-size: 18px 18px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        white-space: nowrap;        
        }
        .cssmenu ul li.current {
        background-image: url('Images/Light_Green_Beveled_Circle.jpg');
        background-position:left center;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

HTML Code here:

```
    <td colspan="2" class="cssmenu">
                <img src="Images/image1-8.png" alt="logo">
                   <ul>
                   <li class="current"><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='UberUns/UberUns.html'><span>Über uns</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='Termine/Termine.html'><span>Termine</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='Angebot/Angebot.html'><span>Angebot</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='Verkaufen/Verkaufen.html'><span>Verkaufen</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='WeitereInfos/WeitereInfos.html'><span>Weitere Infos</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='Kontakt-Lageplan/Kontakt_Lageplan.html'><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href='Intern/Intern.html'><span>Intern</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
    </td>
```

Here is the URL: http://www.boerse-daellikon.ch/index.html

Comment: most of the `background` properties other than `background-image` are not supported in IE8. like `background-size`. you better use a image which is of same image instead of applying `background-size` later..

Comment: You using image 'Light_Green_Beveled_Circle.jpg' with size 93x93px. IE8 will display full size of this image. You can use image with small size to background image

Comment: I would like to give a big thanks for such a quick response! I am very happy to have found this support site :-)

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried a solution with the image sizing and VOILA it does make a difference to have the exact image size relative to the CSS layout however there are still some issues (hopefully small ones) with the layout as compared to the other browsers. This means I must have some different CSS layout code for IE8 (and potentially older) as apposed to all the other browsers & versions which means I need to be able to use different css layout for IE8. Is this possible? Can I check if IE8 is accessing the website and if YES change the CSS code or file?

Answer (score 0):

Some Background Properties arent supported in IE8 im afraid http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

However, you can do 1 of 3 things,

1) provide a correctly sized image (will mean you dont get the nice sharp image on retina displays)

2) implement a polyfill for IE7/8's background image. You can find more information here: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

3) use the transparent gradient hack to sort of combine options 1 and 2.

```
background: transparent url("path/to/non-retina-sized-image.jpg") left center no-repeat;
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent,transparent), url("path/to/retina-sized-image.png");
background-size: 16px 16px;
```

the reason option 3 works is that CSS3 compliant browsers will replace the first line with the second and third. where as IE8 wont understand the transparent linear-gradient and ignore it along with background-size

this was originally suggested as a work around for cross browser support for svgs here: http://pauginer.tumblr.com/post/36614680636/invisible-gradient-technique

Comment: I would like to give a big thanks for such a quick response! I am very happy to have found this support site :-)

Comment: My response here would be the same as I wrote above regarding the image sizing being a workable solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

This conditional comment allowed me to use a specific stylesheet for rendering IE8 only while using another style sheet for all other browsers. This really worked out well as I was able to work with the CSS code to get IE8 working perfectly without messing up the CSS code for all others.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles2_ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

...simple is as simple does...

Comment: :) glad you found a solution, despite your question asking specifically for background-image solutions. Would you mind upvoting or marking an answer as correct for this question